# Add jar to eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to write eclipse plugin. I need to use a jar file in my code.
inside the

```
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
```

The jar file is directly accessed using 
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(checkStyle_cmd);
checkDtyle_cmd is String "java -jar"+"location of jar file"+ (some other stuff).

I created a 'lib' folder. Used it as source folder. Pasted the jar there. Added "/ProjectName/lib/jar_file_name.jar" to Classpath in Runtime. Did not work.
So, also added /Test5/lib/checkstyle-7.1.2-all.jar in bin.includes build.properties. Still no luck. 
I get unable to access jar file error

Comment: If you are trying to run the jar in a separate process it doesn't have to be in the current class path - you just have to pass the **absolute** file path to the java command, but you may also need to tell `exec` exactly where to look for the java command. Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting error "Unamble to access jarfile /Test5/lib/checkstyle-7.1.2-all.jar ". It works with absolute path. But I need to export my project as a jar plugin so other people can use it. So, I need to give relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the absolute path of the jar in your plug-in using something like:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/lib/jar_file_name.jar"), null);

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);

String path = URIUtil.toFile(URIUtil.toURI(fileURL)).getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: What is Bundle and FrameworkUtil? I do not get any suggestions from Eclipse to import these classes

Comment: They are in the `org.eclipse.osgi` plug-in so add that to your plug-in's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to actually extract the code from the jar than to run it from the command line.

Within a .jar folder is the .class files of the byte code, this compiled from .java files and run by the VM.

You can use [this](http://www.javadecompilers.com/) website to decompile .class files.

As far running the code from the command line, as others have said you need to know the absolute path and the relative path may not exist sometimes, it would just be all around better to have all the source code compiled into one .jar rather two .jar's.

Comment: I tried to get path of the jar file using SampleHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource("filename"); It did not work. I tried with a text file. I get output only when the file is in src folder. If it is in lib folder(which i have chaged to source folder) it does not display path